# Having some issues with htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello everyone wondering if i can pick your brains and il be as descriptive as possible.

So i am trying to create a page that will load a title and category (dynamic from database) based upon the selection that is picked by the user

**sitename used as my domain name**

So to be a little clearer i have a file and variables named sitename/2017/slot.php?gp=category&sn=title

the category and title are stored in the database for each row what i want to do is make a clean URL to look like this sitename/2017/slot/category/title/

So when viewing the page like this sitename/2017/slot.php?gp=category&sn=title the page loads everything in and displays correctly and the variables are being set as i can see them in my title in the browser tab

my error comes when i use the mod rewrite to make it clean, once the .htaccess has been changed and uploaded and i navigate to the new clean URL sitename/2017/slot/category/title/ it shows me the variables havent been set as they no longer appear in the title tab of the browser and also the page doesnt use my css. Below i have added my htaccess rule, any help and feedback is greatfully appreciated

```
#change this sitename/2017/slot.php?gp=category&sn=title
#to this sitename/2017/slot/category/title/
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^slot/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/ slot.php?gp=$1&sn=$2 [NC,L]
```

just incase here is the php code im using in slot.php i am connecting to my database fine no issues there and after the code below im running a while loop to get out the data for the row the user clicked on

```
if($_GET['gp'] && $_GET['sn']){
    $gp = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z-]#i', '', $_GET['gp']);
    $sn = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z-]#i', '', $_GET['sn']);
}
```

here is the full code i have in my htaccess

```
#make custom page not found
#ErrorDocument 404 /filenotfound.php

#stop directory file listing in all folders
IndexIgnore *

#make pages have www. in them
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=permanent,L]

#change this slot.php?gp=category&sn=title
#to this sitename/2017/slot/category/title/
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^slot/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/ /2017/slot.php?gp=$1&sn=$2 [R=302]
```

Comment: For example domains please use `example.com`. `sitename` in this context is ambiguous, as it could be perceived as a _subdirectory_. (Hence some confusion below.)

Comment: @w3dk im a new member and it wouldnt allow me to post any kind of domain name thats what it told me when i was writing the question so had to resort to sitename

Comment: The editor won't allow you to post multiple _external links_. To post example URLs, surround them in backticks (inline code formatting) - there is no limit if they are formatted this way.

Comment: @w3dk ok thank you il note that for future refrence

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file located? Your code implies it is in the `/2017` subdirectory (is this a physical directory)? However, the answers are so far assuming it's in the document root?

Comment: @w3dk my .htaccess is in a folder that i created with filezilla when you right click and create directory but the 2017 folder is in the main directory as its a site im currently building

Comment: I think you'll need to add your directory structure to your question, with the location of your `.htaccess` file. "a folder that I created" - what folder is that? The `/2017` directory will need to be on the same filesystem path?

Answer (score 0):

If your URL starts with `2017` you must include it in your RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule ^2017/slot/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/ slot.php?gp=$1&sn=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you explain what is "same result"?

Comment: Same result being the variables are not being set in my php page and no css is being used where as if you take out the mod rewrite and use the original slot.php?gp=category&sn=title everything works fine the variables are set and the css is working

Comment: The css is because you (probably) used relative path (and not absolute) so the browser is looking for the `style.css` file inside `sitename/2017/slot/category/title/style.css` (and not inside `sitename/style.css`). Regarding the variables in PHP - I don't understand what you did get there.

Comment: ok i understand the reason for the css. Regarding the PHP varaibles take a look at the original post i have updated it with the PHP code i have in my slot.php page

Comment: Try to add `var_dump($_GET);` **before** the `if` you got there.

Comment: after trying the var_dump i get this printed to screen array(0) { }

Comment: And what **exactly** is the URL you used (in your browser)?

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing the `^`, which matches the very start of the path (the part after `sitename/`. That is, a rule starting with `^slot/` will match only `sitename/slot/`, not `sitename/2017/slot/`. Your rule should look like this:

```
#change this sitename/2017/slot.php?gp=category&sn=title
#to this sitename/2017/slot/category/title/
RewriteRule ^2017/slot/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/ slot.php?gp=$1&sn=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: ok so i tried your suggestion and still i have the same issue no variables are being received once mod rewrite is used if i take it back to just the original url the get variables are found and used and again the page is not using the css that is set for that page

Comment: Are you trying to direct to sitename/2017/slot.php, or sitename/slot.php? If it's the former, you need the 2017 in both parts of the rule: `RewriteRule ^2017/slot/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/ 2017/slot.php?gp=$1&sn=$2 [NC,L]`

Comment: i just changed the htaccess to match your new suggestion and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

May I join the party?

```
RewriteRule ^sitename/2017/slot/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/ /slot.php?gp=$1&sn=$2 [NC,L]
```

If the `sitename` the domain name, I will change my answer to :

```
RewriteRule ^2017/slot/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/ /slot.php?gp=$1&sn=$2 [NC,L]
```

Which is almost the same as Dekel's, but not exactly :)

Comment: @Dusan Bajic welcome to the party :) i will try what you put and let you know in 2 mins if its a fail or not

Comment: @Dekel which one is that, I fail to find exactly the same one?

Comment: @Dusan Bajic still not working and hopefully everyone will see this that sitename is my domain name i just wasnt allowed to post the domain name more than twice so kept it as sitename for simplicity

Comment: @DusanBajic sorry, didn't nice you put the `sitename` there (which is wrong, btw. the DOMAIN should not be part of the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Oh, that is the domain name? I thought it was all just URI path :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #example.com/2017/slot.php?gp=category&sn=title
> #example.com/2017/slot/category/title/
> ```

You'll need to disable MutliViews. Near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

With MultiViews enabled (part of mod_negotiation) `/2017/slot` is being implicitly rewritten to `/2017/slot.php` (without any query string paramaters) *before* your mod_rewrite directives are being processed.

---

Although it's still not clear where your `.htaccess` file is located. So, there may still be some work to do... If your `.htaccess` file is located at `example.com/2017/.htaccess` then your existing mod_rewrite directives should be sufficient.

However, if your `.htaccess` file is in the document root (ie. `example.com/.htaccess`) then you will need to modify your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^2017/slot/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/ 2017/slot.php?gp=$1&sn=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: So, your existing mod_rewrite directive should be OK. You just need to disable `MultiViews`, as stated. Make sure to clear your browser cache etc. Any luck?

Comment: yep disabled multiviews, cleared my cache and still no result

Comment: This is Apache, but your site is responding from an Nginx server... Are you using Nginx as a front end proxy?

Comment: sounds stupid but how would i know, im on a hosting service through hostmonster

Comment: Well, it certainly looks like you are. Not sure how that exactly affects things though; it certainly adds another layer of complexity. Btw, did you try the temporary redirect, mentioned above? Yes, your server is running Apache, but an Nginx server is sitting in front proxying requests to the Apache backend server. The response is then ultimately returned from the Nginx server. (That is, unless the Apache server is setting the `Server:nginx/1.10.2` HTTP response header!?)

Comment: nope still same result after using the R=302 redirect

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. You literally just added the `R=302` flag, no other changes? The _substitution_ was still: `slot.php?gp=$1&sn=$2`. If that is the case then you should have gotten an error? If you didn't get an error then the directive wasn't processed?

Comment: ok its now redirecting but its showing the main site not the site im building have a look and see what i mean

Comment: Right ok - bit amazed that it works at all to be honest. Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?  For the redirect to be valid you would need to prefix the substitution with `/2017/`, to become `/2017/slot.php?gp=$1&sn=$2` - That _should_ work. (?)

Comment: nope no other directives just the rule to put www in the domain, ok il try that and il change the R=302 back

Comment: The way you've changed your `RewriteRule` it certainly won't work. The _substitution_ is the 2nd argument. The _pattern_ is the first argument and should remain as `^slot/......`.

Comment: I see you've removed the slash prefix, but shouldn't it be `^slot/.....`? I'm afraid I don't know what else to check. What you had before, with MultiViews disabled (but where is that in your `.htaccess` file?), should be sufficient (try a simple example on another server). So, I can only conclude there must be a conflict _somewhere_. Whether this "problem" has anything to do with Nginx I don't know. (Incidentally, to combine the `Options` directive, it should be `Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks`.)

Comment: ok il add it all to the top of my original post and you have a look and see if its right before i upload it to my server

Comment: Yes, that looks ok. It would be more logical to have the `Options` directive at the top of the file (since it applies to the entire file) - but I don't think the order strictly matters. (?)

Comment: thanks for all the help and i hope i havent taken to much of your time, im going to leave it, i have changed everything back to not using htaccess giving me way to big of a headache :) but thanks again